# Why am i not able to extract data on airflow from mongo?

Tags: mongodb, airflow, pymongo, google-cloud-composer

I am extract a data from mongo collection, which works completely fine on my local system but when i upload it gcp and run my DAG it fails because my collection return zero data, why is it happening?

```
segmentData = pd.DataFrame(list(clientconnect['authorSegment'].find())
```

The above code works on my system but not on my airflow dag. Please help.

Comment: Are [additional permissions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control#dag-ui) required?

Comment: yes, i sorted this today, i didn't had permission to acsess that collection. Thanks for you reply.